# Interpreting a diagram from an Alloy perspective versus a UML perspective

Tags: alloy

The book *Software Abstractions* has an example of modeling a bunch of network processes. Each process connects to another process. To depict this, on a piece of paper I drew this diagram:

[image: Each process has a successor]

I interpreted that diagram as: Each process has a successor process.

But then I got to thinking: That's not right. If it were a UML model, then it would be right, but it's not a correct description for an Alloy model.

After some thinking, I arrived at this description: *Process* has a set of (atomic) values; each value represents a process in the network. *succ* has a set of pairs, each pair represents the connection from a process to another. Each value in *Process* is paired to exactly one value from *Process*.

Do you agree with that description? Do you agree that the above diagram represents a very different thing in Alloy than it does in UML?

Perhaps the above diagram is better suited to UML and the following diagram is better suited to Alloy:

[image: Process successor Process mapping]

Would that be a more suitable Alloy diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you gave a semantics to UML class diagrams in their role as abstract data models (rather than as code sketches), the interpretation you give seems reasonable -- and the Alloy version that you give is a just a formalization of that same interpretation. The second diagram you give is a kind of instance diagram, and I would use it as a way to give semantics to the first diagram: that is, the meaning of a class diagram is a set of possible instance diagrams.